# ¿Como redondear las esquinas de un bloque rectangular?

Tags: css

Quiero redondear las esquinas de bloques de 100px de ancho y 20px de alto, me podrían decir por favor como hacerlo?
Dejo el CSS de los bloques a los que deseo redondearles las esquinas :

```css
.bloque{
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(37, 215, 149);
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes lograr con la propiedad [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius).

Por ejemplo, al colocar solo `border-radius: 20px;`, indicas que las 4 esquinas tendrán un borde de `20px`:

```css
.bloque {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(37, 215, 149);
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloque"></div>
```

También puedes bordear una esquina en específica:

```css
.bloque {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(37, 215, 149);
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloque"></div>
```

O también utilizando:

- `border-top-left-radius`.
- `border-top-right-radius`.
- `border-bottom-left-radius`.
- `border-bottom-right-radius`.

```css
.bloque {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(37, 215, 149);
  position: absolute;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloque"></div>
```